# Is there any official way to fetch Apple Calendar data with a http requests and node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, calendar, icloud

I am building an `electron` application with `typescript` and `vue` where I would like to retrieve calendar events for the given day from apple.I found some unofficial package which is able to do that but they are not well maintained and as often mentioned apple can shut it down at any moment.

Is there any official way send a http request and receive data from apple calendar?

Thanks in advance